Python type for dict-like object
I have some function that accepts a dict-like object.
from typing import Dict

def handle(x: Dict[str, str]):
    pass # Do some processing here...

I still get a type warning if I try passing a Shelf to the function, even though the function supports it. How to I specify the type of a dict-like object?

@InSync This question does contain similar answers, but different questions - I would not have found that question by searching for my own question

Use collections.abc.Mapping (typing.Mapping is deprecated):
from collections.abc import Mapping

def handle(x: Mapping[str, str]):
    pass # Do some processing here...


If you're working with a Shelf or any dict-like object, using Dict[str, str] is too restrictive because it expects an instance of dict, not any object with dict-like behaviour. To specify a broader interface for objects that support dictionary-like behaviour, you can use Mapping.
from typing import Mapping
def handle(x: Mapping[str, str]):
    pass  # Do some processing here...

Mapping is a more general type that works for any object that implements the methods of a read-only dictionary. It supports __getitem__, __iter__, and __len__. This should resolve the type warning for passing a Shelf object, as Shelf behaves like a dictionary but is not an instance of dict.
Valid. Using collections.abc.Mapping is correct, especially now that typing.Mapping is deprecated.
